# Pass locals in mdBottomSheets(angular material bottom sheets)

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material, bottom-sheet

I have tried to pass locals in BottomSheet Controller

```
//Bottom Sheet Controller
angular
.module('app').controller('BottomSheetCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Share', icon: 'share-arrow' },
    { name: 'Upload', icon: 'upload' },
    { name: 'Copy', icon: 'copy' },

  ];
   $scope.items.append($scope.Item);
   console.log($scope.items);
});


 //AppCtrl
 angular
 .module('app').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet){

      $scope.openBottomSheet = function() {
            $mdBottomSheet.show({
                template:
                    '<md-bottom-sheet>{{}}</md-bottom-sheet>',
                controller: 'BottomSheetCtrl',
                scope: $scope.$new(true),
                // preserveScope: true,
                locals: {
                   Item:  { 
                    'name': 'Print this page', 'icon': 'print' 
                   },
                }
            });
        };    
});
```

But $scope.Item is not populating. What is the correct way of passing locals in BottomSheet Controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to inject the locals into the bottom sheet controller - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/GqXWzy?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="BottomSheetExample" class="md-padding bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-button flex="50" class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showListBottomSheet()">Show as List</md-button>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
.controller('BottomSheetExample', function($scope, $timeout, $mdBottomSheet, $mdToast) {
  $scope.showListBottomSheet = function() {
    $scope.alert = '';
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
      template: '<md-bottom-sheet ng-cloak>{{Item.name}}</md-bottom-sheet>',
      controller: 'ListBottomSheetCtrl',
      locals: {
        Item:  { 
          'name': 'Print this page', 'icon': 'print' 
        },
      }
    }).then(function(clickedItem) {
      $scope.alert = clickedItem['name'] + ' clicked!';
    });
  };
})

.controller('ListBottomSheetCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet, Item) {
  console.log(Item);
  $scope.Item = Item;
});
```

[Bottom sheet reference](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdBottomSheet)

> `locals` - `{string=}`: An object containing key/value pairs. The keys
>   will be used as names of values to inject into the controller. For
>   example, `locals: {three: 3}` would inject `three` into the controller
>   with the value of 3.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can also set the bindToController property to true. This allows accessing locals in the BottomSheetCtrl. So in the BottomSheetCtrl you can then get the value of Item like this:

`var Item = this.locals.Item;`

JS

```
//Bottom Sheet Controller
angular
.module('app').controller('BottomSheetCtrl', function($scope,
$mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Share', icon: 'share-arrow' },
    { name: 'Upload', icon: 'upload' },
    { name: 'Copy', icon: 'copy' },
  ];
  var Item = this.locals.Item;
  $scope.items.append(Item);
  console.log($scope.items);
});

//AppCtrl
 angular
 .module('app').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet){

      $scope.openBottomSheet = function() {
            $mdBottomSheet.show({
                template:
                    '<md-bottom-sheet>{{}}</md-bottom-sheet>',
                controller: 'BottomSheetCtrl',
                scope: $scope.$new(true),
                bindToController: true,
                locals: {
                   Item:  { 
                    'name': 'Print this page', 'icon': 'print' 
                   },
                }
            });
        };    
});
```